# Metadata in the tar file

Tags: tar, metadata

Scenario:
I've translated the directory(MyDir) to .tar(MyDir.tar) through compress option. The directory contained some files like csv, xml, cef, etc.
When i try to see the content of tar through terminal by using cat command it show the extra line(metadata) at the top of every file, in my application i am using the tar files which show the content of tar in the application.

When i check the tar file manually by going into the folder then it shows correct file.

But in my application and in the terminal it show the metadata in the file content.

Issue: 
I can not use the file format other than tar.

I don't want that metadata (Extra line) in my application.

Can you please give me suggestions to solve this issue, how could i read the tar without metadata.
Thank you.[metadata which added in tar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/479k0.png)

Comment: So don't use `cat`? Use tar's own extraction options instead...

Comment: I am using cat to see the content of tar file only. (for testing purpose).
My issue is how could i exclude(remove) that metadata after converted folder into tar. That metadata compulsory added in tar file, it is fixed at least in my case, so while reading files from tar in my project i don't want that metadata

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cat`, use the proper tools for extracting file contents from the tar archive e.g.

```
tar -Oxf archive.tar
```

or

```
tar -Oxf archive.tar filename
```

if you want to extract the contents of a single file.

From `man tar`:

- `x` : extract files from an archive
- `f` : use archive file or device ARCHIVE
- `O` : extract files to standard output

You could likely also use `cpio` with the `--extract` and `--to-stdout` options.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver! This command worked in the terminal and got expected output. But i want same output in my project. Do you have any idea how could i view/display/access tar file in my java project without that extra info (header/metadata)

Comment: I don't - but a quick google search throws up a bunch of options, most based around the apache commons libraries ex. [Java Code Examples for org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream](http://www.javased.com/?api=org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream)